# Drawing a Horizontal line only in the positive X axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

For the following plot, I drew a Vertical line at x=0 and two Horizontal lines at y=-5 and y=-10, but as my x values run from -24 to +24, the horizontal lines are drawn over the whole range of x. My aim is to have the horizontal lines only in the positive x-region (starting at x=0 and stretching till the end value of x). Any help would be a lifesaver. Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
data= pd.read_table('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_B.txt', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').values 
t=np.arange(-24,24,1)
x=data[:,1]
plt.xlabel('Time Interval (Hours)')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.axvline(x=0,linestyle='--',color='grey')
plt.axhline(y=-5,linestyle='--',color='maroon') #want this horizontal line only in positive x-axis
plt.axhline(y=-10,linestyle='--',color='red') ##want this horizontal line only in positive x-axis
plt.plot(t,x,'green', linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** You can draw the line manually.
The syntax is `plt.plot((x1,x2), (y1, y2))` and it draws a line from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2)

```
plt.plot((0, 24), (-10, -10), linestyle='--', color='red')
```

**Option 2** use the `xmin` argument of axhline. 0 is the far left of the plot, 1 is the far right of the plot. Since your plot is symmetric you need `xmin=0.5` for it start in the middle.

```
plt.axhline(y=-10,linestyle='--',color='red', xmin=0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, Option 2 was something I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it's good in this case, but can be a real pain when the plot isn't centered